# How can I get a number placed in a text message on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-implicit-intent

I want to add a feature to my app that when I touch the number in a message, the user can decide to send the number to my app or Android Dialer.

For example my friend send me a code and i want to use this code for special ussd code that my app run it.

I think I have to use implicit intent but I don't know how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have quoted the below links

-[intent filter](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#intentfilter)

-[Intents implicit\explicit](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#intents_implicit)

> **Implicit intents** specify the action which should be performed and
>   optionally data which provides data for the action.
>
> For example the following tells the Android system to view a webpage.
>   All installed web browsers should be registered to the corresponding
>   intent data via an intent filter.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://www.vogella.com")); startActivity(i);
```

> If an **Explicit intent** is send to the Android system, it searches for all
>   components which are registered for the specific action and the
>   fitting data type.
>
> If only one component is found, Android starts this component
>   directly. If several components are identifier by the Android system,
>   the user will get an selection dialog and can decide which component
>   should be used for the intent.

---

**How to use**

> You can register your own components via **Intent filters**. If a
>   component does not define one, it can only be called by explicit
>   intent.

---

**Register an activity as Browser**

```
<activity android:name=".BrowserActivitiy" 
          android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:scheme="http"/> 
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**UPDATES**

A code sample for [mimeType](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)

```
<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thank you @Srinath  .Do you know I have to choose what kind of action?(If it is not action.SEND)
and what I have to set for data scheme or mimtype?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about a number in a SMS that you received. On clicking that number you want the user to get an option to either dial or use your app.

If yes then you need to include **intent filter** in your manifest file for launcher activity.

Comment: Yes, You exactly understand what I said, but i don't know how to do that?
what action I have to use, what is the category?
I just guess that I have set the mimType number.

Comment: read this and see if you get the answer or any other information. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html and this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html